# Is it possible to start a new process and set it's main window as a child window of my MDI application?

Tags: windows, mdi

Is it possible to start a new process and set it's main window as a child window of my MDI application?

The scenario is: I have a MDI application and I want to start Adobe Acrobat as a child window of my MDI application.

Comment: Do you need the full Acrobat product, or just a way to view PDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, I believe it's possible using [SetParent.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541(VS.85).aspx)

However, in practice, this may be a bit more difficult than you'd expect.  Also, you'll need to do work to syncronize the styles, etc.

Just a thought, though - If you are trying to embed Acrobat Reader (not full Acrobat), you may be able to do this easier by embedding a webcontrol and having the acrobat reader plugin used in that...

---

Here are some samples of people making this work (at least partially):

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170800/embedding-hwnd-into-external-process-using-setparent) with workarounds for specific issues.

[CodeProject article using SetParent](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ByPassAutomation.aspx?display=Print)

[Experts-exchange question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_22842901.html) about embedding a java app in a win32 app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, at least not using SetParent. To quote from the SetParent documentation:

> An application can use the SetParent
>   function to set the parent window of a
>   pop-up, overlapped, or child window.
>   The new parent window and the child
>   window must belong to the same
>   application.

Comment: There are many examples of this working online, though.  For example, see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ByPassAutomation.aspx?display=Print

Comment: That being said, I don't think it's a very good idea in general, but it does appear to be a way to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is easily done, but it could be an option to try to integrate one of the open-source PDF-viewers (if you're prepared to go GPL as that is probably the license on most of them). Some links:

- [epdfview](http://trac.emma-soft.com/epdfview/)
- [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html)
- [evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/)
- [okular](http://okular.kde.org/)