# How to integrate console window in an application like VSCode?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-code

Just like Visual Studio Code's integrated console, I would like to know how it is implemented.

I tried to read VSCode's source code, and I found that it is using xterm.js to provide terminal. Then I tried to read xterm.js's source code, but I didn't find any native(?) code about creating or integrating a terminal.

Maybe I missed something, please give me some advice if you can.

Is it a child process with its window `SetParent`ed to its parent?

> Edit:

My goal is to embed a console window in my application, so that I can quickly run some scripts when using it, just like the experience in VS Code.

Sorry for the ambiguity in the original question.

Comment: You could do so with cmd.exe as child process. You might find some additional hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/170800/1312382). If working with Qt, possibly [this](http://qconsole.sourceforge.net/) is interesting as well, maybe even the links sited [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/6468/embedded-console-in-qt-gui/7). Did not evaluate any of, though...

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). While legal, you cannot safely do it, unless you own both processes, and know *exactly* what you are doing. At a guess, VSCode is opening pipes to a native console window, and just reads its output to its own window.

Comment: Is a console window something you want to implement in one of your own projects?  If so, what do you actually want to _do_ in that window?  If you state your requirements more clearly, you won't get downvoted and you'll get better answers (although the one below is certainly interesting).

Comment: @PaulSanders I've edit the description. I want to embed a console window in my application just like the one in VS Code. I don't mean to reinvent a console screen. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code creates named pipes for console input/output and then spawns the process winpty-agent.exe as well as powershell.exe. winpty-agent.exe opens the named pipes for CONIN$ and CONOUT$ and all input in the terminal window bound to VSCode either uses Read/WriteFile to pass information to and from pipes which then the information is passed to a hidden terminal window spawned by powershell.exe. The pipes are written to and read from each time a character is inputted.

winpty-agent.exe also makes the PowerShell window spawned from powershell.exe a child window and hides it with the flag SW_HIDE. When the window visibility state has the flag set SW_SHOW, it can be seen that every time something is inputted in the terminal bound to VSCode, is also inputted at the same time in the hidden PowerShell terminal window.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) demonstrates how to redirect console input/output between parent and child processes via the utilization of pipes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it later.