# what's the proper way to show exe within my application?

Tags: c#, process, windows-10, embed

Currently I'm using [`SetParent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) to do that. It this "hacky"? is there a better way to do that? if so, how?

here's what I'm using currently:

```
    void LoadApplication(string path, IntPtr handle)
    {
        var p = Process.Start(path);
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, handle);
        SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0040);
    }
```

Comment: How else would it be done? They are separate processes so one being within the other is purely a visual thing. The way to make one window a child of another is to set its parent handle, which is exactly what you're doing. If it feels hacky, it's because showing one application window within another's is a hack to begin with. If a hack is what you need then a hack is what you implement.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459874/good-or-evil-setparent-win32-api-between-different-processes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170800/embedding-hwnd-into-external-process-using-setparent